# Drawing balls with or without replacement and the underlying sample space

Tags: probability

One draws two balls from an urn containing $k$ black and $m$ white balls. The events 'first ball is white' and 'second ball is white' are independent, provided that one sets back the ball after drawing it. I need to prove the statement by defining appropriately 2 probability spaces and draw conclusions if they are independent or not.

Let $A=\{ B_1,B_2,...B_k, B_{k+1}, B_{k+2}, ...B_{n}\}$ be the set of elements of the urn, $\Omega_1 = \{ (B_i,B_j)|\,i,j=1,2...n\}$ the sample space of drawing a second ball from $A$ after returning back the first drawn ball in A. It follows, $|\Omega_1|= {n \choose 2}=\frac {(k+m)(k+m-1)}{2}.$ One defines the power set $P_1$ on $\Omega_1$ to be the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra. One defines a probability measure:
$p:\Omega_1 \rightarrow [0,1]\,$taking into account the number of occurrences of $(B_i, B_j)$. The probability to draw two white balls in a row will be $\,\,\frac {m \choose 2}{k+m \choose 2}.$  The events 'the first draw is white ball' and 'the second ball is white' will be independent if $P(\text{white}, \text{white})= P(\text{white}) P(\text{white})= \frac {m}{k+m} \frac{m}{k+m}.$ Nevertheless, the two last expressions are not equal.

When considering the case of drawing with replacement I have a similar issue. I guess the problem is related to the way the sample space is defined.

Can somebody provide some support ?

Answer (score 2):

$|\Omega_1|=n^2$ and the number of options to draw two white balls is $m^2$. The reason is that you can choose the same ball twice. If it was without replacement your computation was correct and they are not independent.

Comment: Thanks. How do you get $|\Omega_1|= n^2$ and the number of options to draw two white balls $m^2$?

Comment: $n$ options for first ball, again $n$ for second.